# can floated element inherit background color from its wrapper element?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>  
    <style>
        #wrap{
            width: 800px;
            background-color: black;
            color: red;
        }



        #right{
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="right">
            <h1>RIGHT</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Because in this example only the text color was inherited not the background color. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 3):

The `color` property is defined in the [CSS standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#colors) to be inherited from the parent if not set (note the "*Inherited:* Yes" section). The [`background-color` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background-properties) is not (it defaults to `transparent`, and has "*Inherited:* No"). You can always do this, though:

```
#right
{
    float: right;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

When you set `background-color` to `inherit`, it will do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow:auto;` to #wrap to accomplish this:

```
#wrap{
    width: 800px;
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VREHZ/)**

Comment: this is the first time i learn about overflow i will search more about it thanks.